# Visual SVN - How to maintain separate user settings and publish settings?

Tags: c#, svn, visualsvn

For a new MVC web development project, I'm collaborating with a couple of other developers and we want to use Visual SVN to manage source control.

Following the "Getting Started" instructions at the VisualSVN website (http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/getting-started/) seems to to commit everything within the Solution folder including all the settings file (.suo, user, .Publish.Xml)

However, we want to maintain separate Publish Settings within Visual Studio as we publish to our local machines for testing.

Is that possible?

P.S. Shouldn't VisualSVN Client automatically ignore the .suo and .user files?

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't you'll need to either

1. add them to the ignore on commit lists - you can do this while committing but its a per user setting
2. remove them from svn - delete them from svn using tortoise as visual svn cant see them (take copies first, as I think this will actually delete them), commit the delete. Put them back into the folder and commit again, svn will show up these files as uncommited, right click on them and select ignore in the commit window, and commit them, this will apply to everyone. Its easier to not commit them in the first place :)

Answer (score 2):

I use SVN as my source control as well. I also use VisualSVN (but only server side). The main thing I would suggest is to use VisualSVN to host your repositories, but use something else to commit/update/checkout your repositories to your local machine.

I would suggest TortoiseSVN for this. Use TortoiseSVN to control your workflow on local machines. You can then use it to simply right-click/ignore your *.suo files. Or any other files/folders you wish to keep out of the repository!

It may take a bit of research to get it setup. But this is what I use on an every day basis, and it is very user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used VisualSVN, but I would be surprised...no shocked if what you said was true.

Does VisualSVN really by default automatically add and commit user files? You'd think a solution that's built for VisualStudio would simply know better. I would call the company and verify this.

If VisualStudio does commit local user files, I would recommend that you use [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) instead.

Not only does AnkhSVN know better than to commit user files, it's also open source and you can save yourself the $49 per user you need for VisualSVN. And, it's not just the $50 you're paying per user that you pay with VisualSVN either. It's also the fact that you have another license you need to track while users come in and leave the project. Who do you think is going to get that fun job?

However, if you must use VisualSVN, and VisualSVN does commit user local files by default, You need to get my [kitchen sink pre-commit hook](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/newest_svn_hooks.zip). One of the things it does is allow you to completely ban the addition of files such as Visual Studio's *.csuser` files and the other types of VisualStudio detritus.

Of course, you should let developers know how they can [set global-ignores and autoproperties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts) in Subversion. This will prevent them from accidentally adding them. But, there's no way you can configure that globally, or to prevent someone from purposefully adding them. Only my pre-commit hook can keep them out of your repository. After a few failed commits because your developers tried to add in these private user files, your developers will quickly fall into line and set up their global-ignores.